# RavenDB load related data not working

Tags: c#, types, casting, ravendb

The following code throws an exception on the `session.Load<Employee>(order.Employee)`, but I have no problem querying an employee directly.

```
    static void LoadRelatedData()
    {
        using (var session = mystore.OpenSession())
        {
            var employeeFromQuery = session.Query<Employee>().FirstOrDefault();  //works
            var order = session.Include<Order>(o => o.Employee).Load("orders/819"); //works
            var employeeRelatedToOrder = session.Load<Employee>(order.Employee); //EXCEPTION
            var dynamicRelatedToOrder = session.Load<dynamic>(order.Employee); //works
        }
    }

    private static IDocumentStore mystore = new DocumentStore()
    {
        Url = "http://localhost:4444/RavenDB",
        DefaultDatabase = "Hello"
    }.Initialize();
```

The exception I get is -

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Raven.Abstractions.Linq.DynamicJsonObject' to type 'RavenApp.Employee'
```

.

I'm basing my code on http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/Csharp/client-api/querying/handling-document-relationships

The employee and order data are generated by the Raven Create Sample Data task.

Comment: No issues running this on Build 3528; what are you running?

Comment: Did you have any success with the answer below? If not, can you update your question to provide more information>

Answer (score 0):

As you've used Include, the order.Employee should be populated for you and not require a second load.

```
static void LoadRelatedData()
{
    using (var session = mystore.OpenSession())
    {
        var employeeFromQuery = session.Query<Employee>().FirstOrDefault();
        var order = session.Include<Order>(o => o.Employee).Load("orders/819"); 

        // Access them directly, as they have been resolved
        var employeeRelatedToOrder = order.Employee; 
        var dynamicRelatedToOrder = (dynamic)order.Employee;
    }
}
```